# FFmpeg Hardware Acceleration -> GPU + DirectShow

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, gpu, directshow.net

Is there a hardware accelerated version of FFmpeg (e.g. a version that utilizes the GPU)?

Also, does anybody use FFmpeg with GPU support? Possibly for scaling and converting video format?  Or, for example, use DirectShow for image scaling and displaying images on surfaces?
If so anybody can provide small code samples?

Comment: This is probably non-trivial.  This library is multi-platform, so there would need to be separate accelerated codebases for each supported platform.

Answer (score 2):

There are some [VDPAU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) accelerated codecs for unixes with nVidia card. There is also an `mpegvideo_xvmc` codec using [XvMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Video_Motion_Compensation) that can decode MPEG-1 and 2 on X11 if the driver has support for it, and also some codecs using [VA API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API).

For Windows, ffmpeg supports [DXVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX_Video_Acceleration) 2. If you want to use it with DirectShow, you should install [ffdshow tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/), since it provides the necessary DirectShow filter (and it also supports all ffmpeg filters, can display subtitles, etc)