# Hardware accelerated video processing tools for Linux

Tags: cuda, ffmpeg, centos, opencl, nvidia

I am looking into options for command line video processing tools for Linux, but I am having a hard time find any. FFmpeg doesn't support hardware acceleration as far as I can tell and I don't see many alternatives.

The machines that will be running the software are running CentOS and each has a NVIDIA Tesla card available. While the CentOS can be swapped with something else (not Windows), it would be great to have something that supports CUDA or OpenCL.

I don't have any strict requirements for what actually needs to be processed, but I just want to see what options are available for this hardware.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5554933/492336), they mention VDPAU accelerated codecs for unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, now that I looked into it, ffmpeg has support for VDPAU, which is the API for using NVIDIA cards to decoding/encoding video, but ffmpeg supports it for playback only.

The `--enable-vdpau` configure option is autodetected so it is not a requirement to add to `./configure`.

Comment: Does it support very basic CUDA functions? Such as parallelizing a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use: `ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v nvenc  output.avi`